# sql query help, don't know how to term this

Tags: sql

I'm not too sure how to term this question. Stay with me.

I want to create a query to retrieve the rows with x's in the row column in the table(this is a dummy table):

```
row col1 col2 col3 
 x   1    a    c 
 x   2    b    c
 x   3    a    c
     4    b    d
 x   5    f    g
```

So the way I want my query to work is to retrieve all rows where the value for col2 doesn't have a row in col3 where the value is d. Ie. value 'a' will be retrieved because it only has c's for col3, but value 'b' wont be retrieved because it has a *d*  in col3 on the 4th row down.

I hope this is easy to understand.

Ps. Once I know how to do the query I expect I'll know how to phrase the title and will redo it. (although now I think about it, maybe this title is best for all those with questions like mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on everything you've provided, I'll have to make a few assumptions.  Short of doing a self-join on the table, you could take advantage of an identity key on the table to use a simple query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE col3 = 'd');
```

If you don't have an identity key on the table, you could do something more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE col2 NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE col3 = 'd');
```

Both of these queries will return all tuples in the relation that have elements of col2 that are not in tuples where col3 contains 'd'.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Think of how you might do this manually, and put that into your query.

To get all the col3 values you'd write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Use that to filter rows from your selection via a `not in` clause:

```
SELECT 
   col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE col2 not in (SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot. I'd accept both answers if I could.

Comment: No worries, @FinnMaunsell.